# Simple Confirm dialog

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get this example I found on this forum to work.
I want to popup an OK alert when OK is clicked and I want the dialog to close when I click cancel. I will have this code attached to a Cancel button.

How do I declare the element #mydialog?  should it be in my JSP?

```
    $("#mydialog").dialog({modal:true, title:'Dialog Title',
    resizable:false,
    'buttons':{ "OK": function() { alert("OK Clicked")},
    "Cancel":function() {$(this).dialog
    ("close");}}});
```

Thanks

Comment: `#mydialog` is the selector of an element. In this case, it's a HTML element with an `id` of `mydialog`.

Comment: Are you including jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: I understand that it is an HTML element but what form does it take. Do I need to create buttons myself within this #myDialog element etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) It can come directly as a part of your page HTML - rendered using JSP (or any other server side technology you are using)

OR

b) It can be dynamically created just prior to initializing our dialog. This way, the HTML rendered by your server need not worry about it.

For ex:

```
// create if needed
if($('div#mydialog').length == 0) {
    $('<div/>').attr('id', 'mydialog').html('Are you sure?').appendTo('body');
}

// now init the dialog
$("#mydialog").dialog({
...
```